# right way to define pointer to the function

Tags: c

everyone, I have this piece of the code:

```
void foo(int var, int var1)
{
 printf("%d\n", var);
 printf("%d\n", var1);
}

void foo_for_foo( void (*some_function)(int, int))
{
 int x = 5;
 some_function(x, x);
}

int main()
{
 void (*ptr_foo);  // <- look here
 ptr_foo = &foo;
 foo_for_foo(ptr_foo);

 return 0;
}
```

does it matter how do I define pointer to function:

```
1) void (*ptr_foo);
2) void (*ptr_foo)(int, int);
```

my compiler receives both versions

thanks in advance for the explanations of the difference

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The two forms are not equivalent.

`void (*ptr_foo)` is not a function pointer at all. It's a normal, non-function void pointer. The parentheses are superfluous and misleading. It's exactly as if you had written `void* ptr_foo`.

`void (*ptr_foo)(int, int)` is the proper way to declare a function pointer to a function taking two `int`s and returning `void`.

The only reason that this works is because in C, `void` pointers are implicitly convertible to any other type of pointer. That is, you can assign any other pointer to a `void*`, and you can assign a `void*` to any other pointer.

But the fact that this works in this example is essentially an accident of syntax. You cannot in general replace `void (*foo)(int, int)` with `void (*foo)`.

If you try doing that with `some_function` in the argument list to `foo_for_foo`, your compiler will complain when you try to invoke `some_function` because it is not a function pointer.

Similarly, if your `foo` function happened to return an `int` instead of `void`, you would notice the problem right away. Declaring `ptr_foo` as `int (*ptr_foo)` would have resulted in an error on the statement `ptr_foo = &foo` because unlike `void` pointers, `int` pointers are not implicitly convertible to other pointer types.

In short, **always use the second form**. It is the only one that is correct in general, despite this fluky case.

Answer (score 0):

The statement  `void (*ptr_foo);` declares a variable of type `void *`.  The function pointer is cast to this type in the statement `ptr_foo = &foo;` and back to a pointer to the proper function pointer type in the call to `foo_for_foo`.  If you compile with `gcc -Wall` (or whatever extra paranoid settings your compiler supports) you should see a warning about this conversion.

Comment: Actually, gcc doesn't complain about this with `-Wall` or even `-Wextra`, and it shouldn't, since it is standard C to freely convert back and forth between `void*` and other pointer types.